# CSS - How to align text and icon in one line

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I need to align icon and text inside div in one line as is shown in the following picture:

[image]

I use flexbox to place the `shopping-cart-icon` and `shopping-cart-section` in one row.

```css
.shopping-cart-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-icon {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: bbo;
}
.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section .shopping-cart-name {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0px;
}
.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section .shopping-cart-price {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="shopping-cart-container">
    <div class="shopping-cart-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i></div>
    <div class="shopping-cart-section">
        <div class="shopping-cart-name">Shopping cart</div>
        <div class="shopping-cart-price">12 000</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to align icon in div `shopping-cart-icon` and text in div `shopping-cart-price` to the bottom.Can please help me?

Comment: Shopping cart icon and text "12 000" must be inline aligned to the red line in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: Using FLEX**

Here I have used flex for solving the problem, given the property of `display:flex` to the `shopping-cart-section`.
Now you can assign the children of Section i.e. Cart Name and Cart Price their individual Flex properties. Which are `flex-grow`. You can find the flex logic in the below example.

```css
.shopping-cart-container {
  display: flex;
}

.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-icon {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section .shopping-cart-name {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section .shopping-cart-price {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="shopping-cart-container">
  <div class="shopping-cart-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i></div>
  <div class="shopping-cart-section">
    <div class="shopping-cart-name">Shopping cart</div>
    <div class="shopping-cart-price">12 000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2: Using line-height**

Here in the below example, you can check using the `line-height` property.
There can be scenarios where it can break, but changes will be very minute for images this small. But for your case, it's better to use Flexbox.

```css
.shopping-cart-container {
  display: flex;
}

.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-icon {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0px;
}

.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section .shopping-cart-name {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section .shopping-cart-price {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="shopping-cart-container">
  <div class="shopping-cart-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i></div>
  <div class="shopping-cart-section">
    <div class="shopping-cart-name">Shopping cart</div>
    <div class="shopping-cart-price">12 000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to set the height of all elements.

```
.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-icon { height: 50px;}
.shopping-cart-container .shopping-cart-section div {height: 25px; line-height: 25px; width: 150px; font-weight: bold;}
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NavWej

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understood you correctly this can be achieved with a couple of  lines of CSS using Flexbox -

```
.shopping-cart-section {
  display: flex;
  background: green;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Here is Codepen result - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxjJeW